# UiPath Associate and Developer Certification badge to display in resume

Tags: uipath

Where do I download the UiPath Certification Logo for the Associate and Developer Exams?

I want to put the UiPath logo on my resume, but I can't find the download link for a PNG or JPG file on the UiPath site.

Does anyone know where to get the UiPath certification logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, UiPath makes it difficult to find the UiPath Certification Logo on their website.

Basically, they want you to earn the credential. Not just download the image. So they make it a bit harder to find the official [UiPath Certification Logo](https://www.rpacertified.com//2021/03/29/uipath-certification-logo.html) on their website.

**Certmetrics Site**

The proper way to do it is to first pass the exam, and then log into the [certmetrics](https://www.certmetrics.com/) site with the same credentials you used to register for the exam. Click the badges tab and you'll find a link that allows you to download the logo and share your results on Facebook, YouTube or Twitter.

**Validation Link**

The other thing they provide is a link with the verification ID that proves your validation is authentic. If you give that to an employer they will see what version of [UiPath Certification exam](https://www.rpacertified.com//2021/03/27/uipath-certification-study-tips.html) you passed and when you took the test. Here's my link:

https://www.certmetrics.com/uipath/public/badge.aspx?i=1&t=c&d=2020-09-05&ci=UIP00133983

It looks like this when someone clicks on it:

[image]